# No margin on body

Tags: css

My body has a margin of 8px yet in my css I have:

```
body {    
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Why are the styles not being adhered to? The CSS file is being loaded correctly, I have checked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body id="page-name">
        <div id="drag-overlay"></div>
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is your HTML code?

Comment: Is the css file path good? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Do you have any styling on `#page-name` or `#drag-overlay`?

Comment: CSS file loads in and no styling on any other elements.

Comment: create fiddle for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
html, body {    
     margin: 0 !important;
     padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: How is this the correct answer? Only `body` has for the default `margin: 8px` set, not `html`?

Comment: Wait, this solved it? I have never in my life seen a browser with this behaviour, mostly because it's wrong; html should not have any margin or padding. 

Here are the default CSS for Webkit, Firefox and IE: http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/html.css http://www.iecss.com

Comment: Yeah this is odd, only the `<body>` tag has a default margin set - http://www.iecss.com/